# Angular 2 - Access child component property generated from router-outlet

Tags: angular

Normally, I can easily access the child component property from the parent component using @ViewChild.

**App.component.ts** (parent component)

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1> <child-app></child-app>'
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log("This is app component ");
        console.log(this.childComponent.name);
    }
 }
```

**child.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'child-app',
    template: '<h2>This is my child</h2>'
})
export class ChildComponent {
    // some attribute
    name: any = "Kid";

    callChild(): void{
        console.log("Hello, I am your son");
    }
 }
```

It's easy if the child component directive is nested directly inside the parent component. However, in the parent component, if I generate the child dynamically by configuring `route` and using `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, I got the result as undefined.

Do you know how to achive this ?

Comment: Binding with components added by the router is not supported. You can use a shared service instead. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is simply to access a value/method from your child you can simply use the static keyword. see changes below to your code

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ChildComponent } from './child.component';
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: '<h1>My First Angular App</h1> <child-app></child-app>'
    })
    export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
        @ViewChild(ChildComponent) childComponent: ChildComponent

        ngAfterViewInit() {
            ChildComponent.callChild("PArent");
        }
     }


    child.component.ts

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'child-app',
        template: '<h2>This is my child</h2>'
    })
    export class ChildComponent {
        // some attribute
        name: any = "Kid";

        static callChild(txt:string): void{
            console.log("Inside child - Hello, from: " + txt);
        }
     }
```

Comment: this is not how `static` should be used